# System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 1: []

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a batch class which runs monthly and at the end sends an email to the concerned people -

```
global class batchPackageFPMCostUpdate implements Database.Stateful,Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    string PackageNumber = '';
    global List<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        List<Object> ScopeRecords = [select Id,Name from Object];
        return ScopeRecords;
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Object> scope)
    {
        for(Object pac : scope){
            <-----Some Logic----->
        }
        update scope;
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        AsyncApexJob apexJob = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                                FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =: BC.getJobId()];
        String H_L_Emails = Trigger_Support__c.getInstance().H_L_email__c; // Fetch emails from Custom Setting field.
        List<String> Email = H_L_Emails.split(';');                     //Store emails in a String List.
        
        Messaging.singleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String plainTextBody = 'Hi\n';
        plainTextBody += 'Monthly Update Job status is ';
        plainTextBody += apexJob.Status;
        plainTextBody += '\n\nAffected Records are: \n\n';
        plainTextBody += 'Package#\n';
        plainTextBody += PackageNumber;
        plainTextBody += '\n\nHave a good day.\n';
        plainTextBody += 'Company Name';
        
        mail.setToAddresses(Email);
        mail.setSubject('Monthly job Status');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(plainTextBody);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
    
}
```

This code is working perfectly fine in Dev Org but giving me below error in Live Org -

```
System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 1: []
Stack Trace: Class.batchPackageFPMCostUpdate.finish: line 37, column 1
```

Need help on why this is happening?

Comment: Which code is running on `Class.batchPackageFPMCostUpdate.finish: line 37, column 1`

Comment: Do you have trigger for `EmailMessage`?

Comment: Yes, it was a trigger on EmailMessage which in turn was involing a future method. I fixed the trigger on EmailMessage object and that fixed the problem. Thanks guys for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess:

Production has a trigger on `EmailMessage`, which does not exist in your dev environment.
`EmailMessageTrigger` fires `@future` method. As you can see in the image below, @future cannot be executed within the batch.

Your whole transaction looks like that:

Batch -> Messaging.sendEmail -> EmailMessageTrigger -> @future.

---

About `Messaging.sendEmail`

> When org preferences are set to save EmailMessage objects and a trigger is defined for EmailMessage objects, the trigger is fired for each SingleEmailMessage individually.

[image]

---

Resources:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm
- https://salesforceprofs.com/ways-to-mix-asynchronous-apex-without-issues/